# How can i force First Name to be the Display Name in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration

I'm wondering how can i force woocommerce to use the first name entered on registration as the display name.

I have used the following code to add the First & Last name details to my WooCommerce Registration Page

```html
///////////////////////////////
// 1. ADD FIELDS
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'bbloomer_add_name_woo_account_registration' );
  
function bbloomer_add_name_woo_account_registration() {
    ?>
  
    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?> </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First name" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" required="required" />
    </p>
  
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?> </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" required="required" />
    </p>
  
    <div class="clear"></div>
  
    <?php
}
  
///////////////////////////////
// 2. VALIDATE FIELDS
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'bbloomer_validate_name_fields', 10, 3 );
  
function bbloomer_validate_name_fields( $errors, $username, $email ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
  
///////////////////////////////
// 3. SAVE FIELDS
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'bbloomer_save_name_fields' );
  
function bbloomer_save_name_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']) );
    }
  
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67446/130740

Comment: The thing is i don't to use a plug-in for this. I know it can be managed simply with some codings. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `wp_update_user()` you can place it in the action you already have. Give this a try...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'bbloomer_save_name_fields' );
  
function bbloomer_save_name_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']) );
    }
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
    
        if ( !empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && !empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
    
            $display_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) . ' ' . sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] );
            wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $customer_id, 'display_name' => $display_name ) );
        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I cleaned the code a little to make it easier to read. It will do the same thing... just better formatting.

Comment: Lovely! Thank you so much again!